# Can Apple TV work over network only, without the need for HDMI

Tags: appletv

My firm are considering buying an Apple TV box for our new boardroom, so that presentations can be shown directly on the TV, but there is some information about the device that I am unable to find.

Does Apple TV work over network only (providing TV and Apple TV are on the same network)? We are not interested in the apps like Netflix, etc, so we would like to avoid connecting the device via HDMI and thus keep it hidden.

Comment: From what I can understand of the way you think ApopleTV works, I think a visit to an Apple Store is required to a better understanding of the way devices communicate with each other.

Comment: Sadly in my neck of the woods, that is not possible. No Apple store for miles around! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Apple TV video output works solely via HDMI. Audio can also go via optical out. The Apple TV is an AirPlay receiver. What you are suggesting is an AirPlay transmitter, like the iPad and iPhone are, which send a video or audio stream to an AirPlay receiver, like the Apple TV. You won't get around to connecting the Apple TV to the actual display with HDMI.

The Apple TV itself is very small, so you should be able to mount it next to or behind the TV / display. Hiding the Apps is only a cosmetic change. If you don't provide a remote, and set a screen saver which shows e.g. your corporate logo, people will probably not even see the apps, but still be able to connect to the Apple TV via AirPlay.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So just to confirm, as it is a receiver, I wouldn't need it plugged in to the network for AirPlay to work, that can be done wirelessly?

Comment: AirPlay itself can be done via WiFi, yes. Performance via wired ethernet might be faster though. But in my experience, a good WiFi network is sufficient.